# How to use $ in xs:pattern?

Tags: regex, xsd

In our application we define variables starting with "${" followed by variableName and a closing "}".
But the following versions does not work:
`<xs:pattern value="\$\{*\}" />`
`<xs:pattern value="[${]*\}" />`
I think i did not escape the $ s properly, but did not find out how to do it.

Comment: Escape it. Or, use in square brackets.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but i tried the two versions above but they are not working.

Comment: `$` and `{` are two chars that make a sequence, right? Do what I said: escape `$`. `"\${"`. Or put the `$` inside brackets: `"[$]{"`. If you plan to match a string like `${...}` use `"\$\{.*}"`. Or `"\$\{[^{}]*}"`. I see your question is actually more complex than what you put in the title and the initial question body.

Comment: Thanks now it works: \$\{[a-z]+\}

Comment: So, you also had a "hidden" requirement for `variableName` syntax.